# How do the Son'a torpedoes hit the Enterprise so quickly?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-insurrection

In *Star Trek: Insurrection*, there's an encounter between the *USS Enterprise E* (under Riker's command) and two *Son'a* ships.The dialogue goes like this:

> OPS OFFICER: Commander, I'm showing two *Son'a* ships on an intercept course.
>
> RIKER: **How long till they reach us?**
>
> OPS OFFICER: **Eighteen minutes.**
>
> GEORDI: We won't be able to get a transmission out of here for at least another hour.
>
> LT. DANIELS: They're hailing us. *[Daniels is the tactical officer]*
>
> RIKER: Tell them our transceiver assembly is down, we can send messages but not receive them.
>
> LT. DANIELS: I don't think they believe us.
>
> RIKER: Why not?
>
> *[AN EXPLOSION ROCKS THE SHIP]*
>
> RIKER: **Photon torpedo.** Isn't that the universal greeting when communications are down?
>
> GEORDI: I think it's the universal greeting when you don't like someone.

---

**How can the Son'a hit the Enterprise with a torpedo from 18 minutes away?**

Sub-questions:

- Are torpedos really that much faster than ships?
- Was the Son'a torpedo launced much earlier and just not detected in time?
- Is this somehow related to the environment inside the "briar patch"?

Comment: They were travelling at plot speed. It may be greater than warp speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Photon torpedoes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Photon_torpedo) are warp-capable munitions, so while at sublight speeds the Son'a ships might be 18 minutes away from interception (whatever that means in 3D space), this is not a restriction for photon torpedoes. @Valorum rightly points out that photon torpedoes not fired at warp will not cross the warp threshold, but instead travel at high-sublight speeds. How high probably varies by writer, but it might not be impossible for one to travel "18 minutes" (in ship speed) in a fraction of that. Also, it is possible (though probably unlikely) that the Son'a had self-warp-capable photon torpedoes.

*Why don't the Son'a ships warp in (or just go faster) to get to the Enterprise faster?*

This is due to the technobabble in the Briar Patch preventing them to do so. A photon torpedo, being tiny and not filled with people, is an expendable way to attack a ship quickly in the badlands, as if the torpedo goes off course or is destroyed by a gravitational eddy, there is no real loss.

Comment: You might want to mention that photons are typically only warp-capable if fired from a source that's already moving at warp